# Read node titles from Firebase using Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Using Android Studio I want to read from the following Firebase database:

[image]

I want to display the 'eng', 'fra' and 'nld' in a listview, but I don't know how to read that data. In other words, I don't know how to read the title of a node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to read the title of the nodes:

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("tags");
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
          String classnames=datas.getKey();

            }
       }
     @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

By iterating inside the direct children of the child `tags` and using `getKey()` you will be able to get the class names.( 'eng', 'fra' and 'nld')

Comment: Oh haha wow that simple.. I thought getKey() would return the key for the push or something. But thanks a lot for the quick response!

Comment: no problem! yes its not only for push, it just gives you the source location of the snapshot https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getKey().